# How to generate random fragments in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this project, a quiz app to be specific. I have 10 questions to be asked and I want it to be randomly appear in my app. As of now, I put those questions on Fragments using Tabbed Activity. I have no idea how to randomize it.

Should I use Activity rather than fragments?

This is the code where I call those fragments:

```
public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return new FirstFragment();
            case 1: return new SecondFragment();
            case 2: return new ThirdFragment();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any recommendations/suggestions? I really need this app to be done. Thanks!

Comment: If all Fragments are the same (they display a question), then just randomize the question and use a single Fragment to show it per question. Then add 10 instances of the same class with different questions.

Comment: @cricket_007 I was about to suggest something similar. OP could just use a single fragment, load all the questions and options in an array/arraylist and then display..!

Comment: @Taslim This question is two years old ;)

Comment: Wow!! Didn't realize that @cricket_007. Lol!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an array for those Fragments:

```
Class[] classes=new Class[numberOfDirrefentFragmenTypes];
Class c1 = FirstFragment.class;
Class c2 = SecondFragment.class;
classes[0]=c1;
classes[1]=c2;
```

Then you can pick a random class and instantiate it:

```
Random random=new Random();
Class randomClass=classes[random.nextInt(classes.size())];
```

So you can create a random fragment at any time:

```
Constructor<?> ctor = randomClass.getConstructor();
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

It might not be the optimal solution, but it should work.

I hope it helps (I did not compile the code).

Comment: Fragments don't have a String parameter constructor. Also, why not just make an Arraylist of Fragment instances and just get a random one? Reflection seems overkill here

Comment: He might have hundreds of different fragments later. If he instances each of them, it'll suffer performance. I agree about he should choose what to use considering the project.

Comment: In my comment above, I suggested using, say `QuestionFragment` class, that just takes a String argument. Then it's one class to many strings instead of one string per many Fragment classes

Comment: I agree, that sounds like a good change. My answer is an alternative, if he chooses otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, I hope to help others who have the same needs

[Fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment) have a special (static) method called `instantiate(Context, String)` that you can use like this:

```
CustomFragment cf = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), CustomFragment.class.getName())
```

So if you need to generate a random fragment from a list of fragments, you can do it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> fragList = new ArrayList<>();
fragList.add(FirstCustomFragment.class.getName());
fragList.add(SecondCustomFragment.class.getName());
fragList.add(ThirdCustomFragment.class.getName());

int r = new Random().nextInt(fragList.size());

Fragment cf = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), fragList.get(r));
```

You can also pass a series of params with the `bundle` argument (`Fragment.instantiate(Context, String, Bundle)`) . Its an option args that you can use in the fragment's `onCreate` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        customData = getArguments().getString("data");
    }
}
```

if you want to see how it works under the hood take a look [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#578), you'll see that is not heavier for the device and its a good way to not use the reflection by yourself